# PHP - does this syntax actually execute the command?

Tags: php, command

While trying to clean some old code in a project, I ran accross these lines:

```
$cmd = "mkdir -p ".dirname($target);
`$cmd`; // Auto creating folder if needed
```

I tried to run this on a separate script and it does not create a folder (as I expected), but I wonder if i'm missing something where this can actually work ?

Note: The `$cmd` is not used anywhere else

Comment: This works only in Linux and Mac. Allows you to create the directory and intermediate directories between your current position and the target directory using single console command instead of two or more. Directory with a path /documents/priority/tests/ - if you don't have that whole structure already in place, normally you would have to do it in three stages: mkdir documents & cd documents, mkdir priority & cd priority and finally mkdir test. With -p you can do it in one line: mkdir -p documents/priority/tests and it will create the whole directory tree if any parts of it are missing.

Comment: Backticks are the [execution operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) in PHP.  As indicated in the documentation: "The backtick operator is disabled when safe mode is enabled or shell_exec() is disabled."  So you are probably running it under one (or both) of those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other members already said backticks are [execution operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php). You could possibly check if you got any output from command using `echo` before "execution" like below:

```
$cmd = "mkdir -p ".dirname($target);
echo `$cmd`;
```

Anyway IMHO using backticks might be a bit confusing so you could possibly use [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) which is bit more clear what's happening there. For example:

```
$output = shell_exec("mkdir -p ".dirname($target));
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

From other hand, do you really have a need there to create directory that way? You could possibly replace it by using [mkdir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function like following adjusted example from documentation:

```
if (!mkdir(dirname($target), 0777, true)) { // true argument stands for recursive - equivalent of -p in mkdir in linux command
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
// mkdir() function returns boolean value so you can easily know if directory was created or not
```

Regarding place where your directory is being created I would take a look what is being returned from [dirname()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) of `$target` and [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) function for current working directory to see if everything is as expected.

```
echo dirname($target);
echo getcwd();
```